# Problemas em uma consulta realizada dentro de uma Stored Funcion no Mysql

Tags: mysql, funções, stored-procedures

Estou com um problema dentro de uma consulta no `Mysql` realizada dentro de uma `Funcion`.

A questão é a seguinte, entre as varias atividades que a função ai realizar, está testar se certo dado já foi inserido em uma tabela.

A tabela é simples, possui o *ID (chave primária) id_fb (chave estrangeira) e a data de inserção do dado (datetime)*.

Quando executo a *query no phpMyAdmin*, ele retorna os valores corretos, mas quando executo a mesma *query* dentro da função, ele torna o valor da primeira linha da tabela.

A função é a seguinte (apenas com a parte que interessa)

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION teste1 (id_fb INT)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(512)

  BEGIN

    DECLARE ID_final varchar(20);

    SELECT `id` INTO ID_final FROM `brindes_teste` WHERE DATE(`data_hora`) = CURDATE() AND `id_fb` = id_fb LIMIT 1;

    RETURN CONCAT('JÁ PARTICIPOU HOJE = ', ID_final, ' ID_FB=' ,id_fb );        

 END $$
```

A tabela é a seguinte:

> Estrutura para tabela `brindes_teste`

```
CREATE TABLE `brindes_teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_fb` bigint(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_hora` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabela brindes - DEV';
```

> Fazendo dump de dados para tabela `brindes_teste`

```
INSERT INTO `brindes_teste` (`id`, `id_fb`, `data_hora`) VALUES
(2, 1235900, '2016-09-18 00:00:00'),
(3, 1441809, '2016-09-18 00:00:00'),
(4, 1453793, '2016-09-18 00:00:00'),
(7, 1249127, '2016-09-18 00:00:00'),
(9, 1737770, '2016-09-18 00:00:00');
```

Quando realizo a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `brindes_teste` WHERE DATE(`data_hora`) = CURDATE() AND `id_fb` = 1249127 LIMIT 1;
```

> O resultado é 7, o que é o esperado

Agora, quando a mesma consulta é realizada dentro da funcion:

```
SELECT teste1(1249127)
```

> O resultado é 2 (id do primeiro registro da tabela)

Alguém consegue identificar a origem do problema?

Comment: Tente alterar seu retorno para o tipo bigint e sua variável ID_final e retorne sem fazer o cancat,  isso elimina uma boa parte do seu problema depois tente converter e concatena para retornar uma string

Answer (score 0):

Altere o nome da sua variável de entrada. Sempre bom colocar um prefixo no nome das variáveis para não confundir com o nome da coluna. ex: p_id_fb. p = parâmetro.
Ex:

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION teste1 (p_id_fb INT) -- Nome da váriavel diferente do nome da coluna da tabela
   RETURNS VARCHAR(512)

  BEGIN

DECLARE ID_final varchar(20);

SELECT `id` INTO ID_final FROM `brindes_teste` WHERE DATE(`data_hora`) = CURDATE() AND `id_fb` = p_id_fb LIMIT 1;

RETURN CONCAT('JÁ PARTICIPOU HOJE = ', ID_final, ' ID_FB=' ,p_id_fb );        

 END $$
```

Comment: arllondias, procure dar exemplos, copie o códio da pergunta e mostre o que está dizendo alterando nele. É melhor para quem está com dúvida entender. Se possível implemente com o "porque" que é bom usar prefixo com nome, dando referências, etc... quanto mais informação e explicado, melhor.